# How can I close JMS connection and stop it from listening?

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic, spring-jms

I am new to this technology. I am humbly asking for your inputs. I would like to stop my JMS from listening and delete my queue in the ActiveMQ console. I am using ActiveMQ and Spring. Here is the code for getting my queue:

```java
     public boolean deleteQueue(String sessionID) {

            try {
                ActiveMQConnection connection = (ActiveMQConnection) jmsTemplate.getConnectionFactory().createConnection();
               connection.start();
                connection.destroyDestination(new ActiveMQQueue(sessionID));

    //             connection.destroyDestination(new ActiveMQQueue(sessionID));
                connection.stop();
                connection.close();



            } catch (JMSException e) {
                System.out.println("Error handled" + e);
            }

            return true;
        }
```

I have this `MessagingContextConfig` file for the configuration

```
    @Configuration
    public class MessagingContextConfig {

        private static final String DEFAULT_BROKER_URL = "tcp://localhost:61616";//added ?jms.alwaysSessionAsync=true  Feb 4

        @Bean
        public ActiveMQConnectionFactory activeMQConnectionFactory(){
            ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory();
            connectionFactory.setBrokerURL(DEFAULT_BROKER_URL);
            connectionFactory.setTrustedPackages(Arrays.asList("icomm.oss.chat"));

            return connectionFactory;
        }

        @Bean
        public JmsTemplate jmsTemplate(){
            JmsTemplate template = new JmsTemplate();
            template.setConnectionFactory(activeMQConnectionFactory());

            return template;
        }
    }
```

How can I close or stop the connection here? I can't use `connection.close()`. Can anyone help me?

Comment: MessagingContextConfig is from separate file

Comment: Normally a JMS connection is a long-living object, because establishing new connection is a time consuming operation. Often connections are pooled to avoid closing and reopening them. It makes your requirement a bit unusual. Could you please provide some details on the scenario you're going to implement?

Comment: I created a realtime chat application, I used angularJs so that I can receive the messages real time, Every time I Initiated a chat, 2 queues has been created, for this scenario I will name them , chatSesionID and chatSessionID_Response, I have end session button that will call the function deleteQueue, I want my connection to stop from listening when I trigger the button end session and I also want the 2 queues with the name of chatSessionID and chatSessionID_Response be deleted or removed in my activemq Console.

Comment: By the way sir @Daniil thank you for your response.

Comment: I suggest to take a look at temporary queues in active mq request-response example: https://activemq.apache.org/how-should-i-implement-request-response-with-jms